# More family friendly phrase for "always use your full ***"

Tags: phrase-requests, offensive-language

There's a saying that goes something like:

> Never half ass anything. Always use your full ass.

Is there another succinct way of expressing this in more polite language?

---

I think there are a number of concepts conveyed simultaneously, to varying degrees:

- Don't be lazy.
- Fully commit to what you do.
- As @jim points out in the comments, "If it's worth doing, it's worth doing right."
- Take responsibility for your actions, or perhaps, take pride in your work.
- Pick and choose your battles. Or perhaps, don't spend time on things that don't matter.

Comment: What is the "this" that you understand this saying to express? Does using one's "full ass" suggest a better, more committed effort, or a more complete screw-up, or both?

Comment: If it's worth doing, it's worth doing right.

Comment: @BrianDonovan expanded my post. I imagine this most frequently being uttered by some trade master half-seriously admonishing an apprentice after a careless mistake, but I also feel like it's good advice to follow in general.

Comment: Do you know the actual expression?? It is: to do something in a half-assed way. Your author has made it into a verb. People take these liberties with English because they can. But it really isn't a verb per se.

Comment: Do you know the base expression here?? It is not a verb: to do something in a half-assed way. It means to not do something the right way or fully. People take liberties with English because they can not because the expression predates their use of it.

Comment: Never do any thing half fast- always go full throttle.  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the vein of "If it's worth doing, it's worth doing right,"  there is the expression, "Don't run off half-cocked."  My dad used to say that when we didn't prepare properly or did a task poorly due to not thinking about it enough.

Answer (score 2):

I'm familiar with half-assing something, and with the past participle (e.g. a half-assed assignment), but I've never heard of using one's full ass or whole ass. In any case, there's "give 110 percent," "always give it your all" "give it your best effort" "do your best," etc. What I think would align the best with half-ass and whole-ass is doing something "halfheartedly" and "wholeheartedly."

Answer (score 1):

In the case where you're referring to making a major commitment: 
*Don't try to sit on two chairs at the same time.* This kind of has the "ass" thing going too.